# Trying to read an input from stdin into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I want to be able to input:

```
Avoid:
alice bob carol dave eve
```

and have {alice,bob,dave,eve} in the arraylist avoid

```
package lunch;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetsDoLunch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "";
        ArrayList<String> avoid = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Avoid:");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            s = sc2.next();
            if(s.equals("")){
                break;}
            avoid.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
        for (int i = 0; i < avoid.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(avoid.get(i));
        }
```

I'm pretty sure something it's something to do with the sc2.next(); 
I enter the input line after Avoid: and then nothing happens even after I press enter

Comment: use `sc2.nextLine()`

Comment: Your loop never stops because this condition `s.equals("")` is never `true`. Also, `next()` blocks until new values are available.

Comment: Why not try `Arrays.asList()` to convert the scanner input into an ArrayList much more easily: https://repl.it/Fldv/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    ArrayList<String> avoid = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Avoid:");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean flag = true;
    s = sc2.nextLine();
    String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        avoid.add(words[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("done");
    for (int i = 0; i < avoid.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(avoid.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works!!!!

Comment: Then Close this question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of s = sc2.next() use s = sc2.nextLine()

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: I just tried and its working. There must be something else in your code that is not working. Debug

Comment: I am agree with Ezio **output** *Avoid:
a
b
c

done
a
b
c*